# Symmetry of a Manhattan Distance

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces

I am having trouble with proving that the Manhattan distance (also known as [Taxicab geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry)) is a metric by satisfying the condition of symmetry.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you be more specific with your question?

Comment: So I am basically looking for direction in how to prove that the abs(x-y) = abs(y-x).

Answer (score 3):

This is for the Manhatten distance in $\mathbb{R}^n$. If you only need to prove it for dimension two say, then simplify as necessary.

$$d(x,y)=d((x_1,\ldots x_n),(y_1,\ldots,y_n)) $$ $$= \sum_{i=1}^{d}\lvert x_i-y_i\rvert = \sum_{i=1}^{d}\lvert y_i-x_i\rvert $$ $$= d((y_1,\ldots y_n),(x_1,\ldots,x_n))=d(y,x)$$

---

Here's a proof that $|x-y|=|y-x|$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$.

Let $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ and suppose that $x-y\geq 0$. Then $|x-y|=x-y$ and $y-x\leq 0$ so $|y-x|=-(y-x)=x-y=|x-y|$

Suppose that $x-y\leq 0$. Then $|x-y|=-(x-y)=y-x$ and $y-x\geq 0$ so $|y-x|=y-x=|x-y|$

In both cases we have $|x-y|=|y-x|$ as required.

Comment: So I understand the basic idea of the symmetry idea, but I can't seem to find a start place to prove that abs(x-y) = abs(y-x).

Comment: I've added a proof of that fact in my answer.

Comment: Ok, so I had much longer winded version of that, so thank you for confirming that Daniel.

Comment: There's always the one-liner $$|x-y|=\sqrt{(x-y)^2}=\sqrt{(-1)^2(x-y)^2}=\sqrt{((-1)(x-y))^2}=\sqrt{(y-x)^2}=|y-x|$$.